# Return to the desired place in the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the button is clicked, my list is replaced with a one-item list. When I click on the "return to list" button, I want to return to the same list and to the same place in the list to which I scrolled.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.specialOfferRestaurant) {
        localStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', String(window.scrollY))
        localStorage.setItem('restaurants', JSON.stringify(allRestaurants));
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
        setAllRestaurants([props.specialOfferRestaurant])
    } else if (!props.specialOfferRestaurant && localStorage.length > 0) {
        setAllRestaurants(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('restaurants')))
        window.scrollTo(0, Number(localStorage.getItem('scrollPosition')))
        localStorage.clear();
    }
}, [props.specialOfferRestaurant])
```

In this code, everything works except for the line that returns the scroll to the right place. The same line that returns the scroll to 0 also works.

The scroll position is stored in localStorage without problems. If I add this to the bottom of the code:

```
console.log(Number(localStorage.getItem('scrollPosition')))
```

I see that the correct scroll Y value is stored in localStorage

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, you can use the `window.pageYOffset` property instead of the `window.scrollY` property to get the scroll position of the page. The `window.pageYOffset` property is updated whenever the page is scrolled, either manually or programmatically.

> ***updated answer as new description***
> To fix this issue, you can use a separate useEffect hook to update the list, and ensure that it is executed after the scroll position has been set. This will ensure that the list is updated before the page is scrolled, and the scroll position is correct.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (props.specialOfferRestaurant) {
  localStorage.setItem("scrollPosition", String(window.scrollY));
  localStorage.setItem("restaurants", 
  JSON.stringify(allRestaurants));
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  setAllRestaurants([props.specialOfferRestaurant]);
} else if (!props.specialOfferRestaurant && localStorage.length > 0) {
  setAllRestaurants(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("restaurants")));
  window.scrollTo(0, Number(localStorage.getItem("scrollPosition")));
  localStorage.clear();
}
}, [props.specialOfferRestaurant]);

useEffect(() => {
 if (props.specialOfferRestaurant && localStorage.length > 0) {
  setAllRestaurants(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("restaurants")));
 }
}, [props.specialOfferRestaurant]);
```

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't describe the problem correctly. The scroll position is stored in localStorage without problems. I have added a description above.

Comment: To fix this issue, you can use a separate useEffect hook to update the list, and ensure that it is executed after the scroll position has been set. This will ensure that the list is updated before the page is scrolled, and the scroll position is correct.

Comment: I've updated the answer.
I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was found thanks to @Md. Mohaiminul Hasan and it comes from the assumption that the list from localStorage does not have time to render and therefore the scroll cannot be applied to the middle of the list. The final, working code looks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!props.specialOfferRestaurant && localStorage.length > 0) {
        window.scrollTo(0, Number(localStorage.getItem('scrollPosition')))
        localStorage.clear();
    }
}, [allRestaurants]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (props.specialOfferRestaurant) {
        localStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', String(window.scrollY))
        localStorage.setItem('restaurants', JSON.stringify(allRestaurants));
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
        setAllRestaurants([props.specialOfferRestaurant])
    } else if (!props.specialOfferRestaurant && localStorage.length > 0) {
        setAllRestaurants(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('restaurants')))
    }
}, [props.specialOfferRestaurant])
```